# Delete current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to make a button so users can delete their account but I am having trouble.

edit.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "delete", @user, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Account Deleted"
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

This is what I have so far but the problem is that the link is going to the users page and not the destroy method in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out had to change it to a `button_to` rather then a `link_to` because `link_to` was giving me a `href` that was going to the users show page rather then calling the destroy in the controller.